# Incorrect function answer

Tags: kotlin

I have an function, that formats input string to formatted for html string

```
For example, lorem ipsum *dolor sit amet* consectetur **adipiscing** elit.
```

Where

```
* is for <i>
** is for <b>
```

So, output string could be:

```
Lorem ipsum <i>dolor sit amet</i>, consectetur <b>adipiscing</b> elit.
```

I have written this function:

```kotlin
val input = "Lorem ipsum *dolor sit amet*, consectetur **adipiscing** elit."                                      

val tagMap = mapOf(                                                                                               
        '*' to "<i>",                                                                                             
        '♥' to "<b>",                                                                                             
        '♦' to "<s>"                                                                                              
)                                                                                                                 

val tagMapClose = mapOf(                                                                                          
        '*' to "</i>",                                                                                            
        '♥' to "</b>",                                                                                            
        '♦' to "</s>"                                                                                             
)                                                                                                                 

fun tagCheck(obj: String): String {                                                                               
    var str = Regex("""\*\*""").replace(obj, "♥")                                                                 
    str = Regex("""~~""").replace(str, "♦")                                                                       
    str = Regex("""\*\*\*""").replace(str, "♥*")                                                                  
    val charList = str.toList()                                                                                   
    var res = ""                                                                                                  
    val indexMap = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()                                                                    
    var ct = 0                                                                                                    

    for ((tag, define) in tagMap) {                                                                               
        val tagIndex = mutableListOf<Int>()                                                                       
        var status = true                                                                                         
        for (char in charList) if (char == tag) tagIndex.add(charList.indexOf(char))                              
        ct = if (tagIndex.size % 2 == 1) tagIndex.size                                                            
        else tagIndex.size + 1                                                                                    

         for (i in 0 until ct - 1) {                                                                               
           if (status) {                                                                                         
                indexMap[tagIndex[i]] = tagMap.getValue(tag)                                                      
                status = false                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                     
            else if (!status) {                                                                                   
                indexMap[tagIndex[i]] = tagMapClose.getValue(tag)                                                 
                status = true                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                         
                                                                        }                                                                                                             
for (item in charList) {                                                                                      
        res += if (indexMap.keys.contains(charList.indexOf(item))) indexMap[charList.indexOf(item)]               
        else item                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                             
    return res                                                                                                    
    }
```

But in output i get this:

```
Lorem ipsum </i>dolor sit amet</i>, consectetur </b>adipiscing</b> elit.
```

So, function can't check for opened or closed tag, it simply writes only closed tags, what should I do?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110749/regular-expression-to-convert-mark-down-to-html (read all answers)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using a markdown parser instead. These are likely to be more accurate, and suffers less from edge cases than regex.

That being said, you can parse it with regex. However, your approach fails because of the way you handle the tokens. You assign the markdown tokens to different unified tokens (which alone is an unnecessary conversion), and then assign the same token to two different closing tags. That and the loop likely makes all the tags end up as closing tags.

Storing the tokens isn't a bad idea, so let's start off with that. Create connections between `**` and `b`, and `*` and `i`. `***` to `bi` isn't necessary - at the end of this, the parsing will convert these in steps and make `***content***` into `<b>*content*</b>` first, then convert it to `<b><i>content</b></i>`. I map by regex in this case to make it easier later:

```
val tokens = mapOf(
    "\\*\\*" to "b", "\\*" to "i", "~~" to "s"
)
```

The regex itself is more complicated:

Matching empty ones shouldn't happen, spaced ones should be ignored, and it needs to be done for two different types.

Anyway, we have a core regex:

```
val core = "(?<!\* )(?=\S)(.+?[*]*)(?<=\S)(?<! \*)"
```

Note that this alone **will not work alone**. The first and last groups are to avoid `*** something***` being parsed as valid, because `*` is a valid char in the inner one too.

In this case, I defined a `var string: String` in the example, but you can of course replace this with something else. It's just for portability.

```
var string = "***this*** **is** a ***test of* a markdown *regex* parsing system** that I really **hope *works* like it's supposed to**. " +
        "And an ** invalid one **, and not to forget ~~the broken regex~~ the perfect regex"

for ((token, html) in tokens) { // if you don't know, Map entries can be unpacked like tuples. The token is for an instance **, and html is b
    val modRegex = "$token$core$token".toRegex() // Construct the regex. This is why the format in the map is regex-style
    string = string.replace(modRegex, "<$html>$1</$html>")//And finally, we replace it. The String templates ensure the right match, `$1` is the first capture group to avoid losing content

}
```

For the sake of the demo, I also printed `string`:

> ```
> <b><i>this</i></b> <b>is</b> a <b><i>test of</i> a markdown <i>regex</i> parsing system</b> that I really <b>hope <i>works</i> like it's supposed to</b>. And an ** invalid one **, and not to forget <s>the broken regex</s> the perfect regex
> ```
>
> ***this*** **is** a ***test of* a markdown *regex* parsing system** that I really **hope *works* like it's supposed to**. And an ** invalid one **, and not to forget <s>the broken regex</s> the perfect regex

Now, regex is far from perfect, especially when it comes to markdown. There are several edge cases and incorrect handling that comes from incorrect markdown in the first place. You can't just place random tokens around and have that interpreted as valid markdown. As such, incorrectly placed tokens will likely result in improper handling and parsing, which is again why I highly recommend using a markdown parser than using regex.

And while this can be extended to other tokens, **this does not work with links**. `()[]` requires shifting groups around HTML to work, and there are two relevant groups. `($1)[$2]` -> `<a href="$1">$2</a>`, and that again ignores alt text on the URL.

Anyway, the code in this answer should still help you on the regex parsing system, even though it's far from perfect.